# How to combine a collection with the object of a different collection without relation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections;

```
//db.cities.find({})

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
    "Name" : "Istanbul"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
    "Name" : "Ankara"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
    "Name" : "Izmir"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
    "Name" : "Eskisehir"
}
```

```
//db.dates.find({})

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Turkey",
    "dateTime": "2021-09-03 10:25"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "England",
    "dateTime": "2021-09-03 08:25"
}
```

I want to combine two collections but not like `inner join`.

Here is the result I want to see;

```
//the output that I need

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
    "Cities": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
            "Name" : "Istanbul"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
            "Name" : "Ankara"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
            "Name" : "Izmir"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("/*...*/"),
            "Name" : "Eskisehir"
        }
    ],
    "DateTime" : "2021-09-03 10:25"
}
```

As a result, I don't want to see the `DateTime` in all `cities` elements.
How can I get this result in MongoDB v3.2?

Note 1: The `cities` collection doesn't have the `Country` field. I can write `Turkey` as hardcoded in the query.

Note 2: I prefer `aggregate` instead of map-reduce if is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 3.6, MongoDB allows execute [Subqueries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection)

Try this one:

```
db.dates.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "cities",
      "pipeline": [],
      "as": "Cities"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "Turkey"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      _id: "$$REMOVE",
      "Country": "Turkey"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9RmXgj-_Zsh)

Comment: Is there any way to aggregate from `cities`? Because I need to use the pipeline for `cities` but the version of MongoDB is 3.2 that I use. So I can't use the pipeline for the `cities` in your solution.

Comment: @TolgaCakir Subquery is allowed since 3.6 (and you can define your pipeline here `"pipeline": [],`). Unfortunately, you need to migrate to 3.6. There no way to do `$lookup` without the condition in previous versions